# browse from music folder into assets folder android

Tags: android

i'm making a little app to play music, i would like to select a song from the music folder and transfer it to my app's assets folder. Is there any way to achieve that? I don't even know where to look for this. Need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to copy data into an app's assets folder (your own app or otherwise.)

What are you trying to achieve? You should be able to do everything you like with a file from the SD card.

Comment: i'm trying to get a music file that is already in the phone and edit it, like an audio edit tool. So once the the application is compressed to the .apk it's impossible to reach the assets folder?